# peewee not using dynamic table name in select statement

Tags: python, peewee

Why does the select statement here have `t1` instead of `MyDynamicTable`?

```
from peewee import *

database = SqliteDatabase(None)


class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database


class MyTable(Base):
    FieldA = TextField()
    FieldB = TextField()


mytable = type('MyDynamicTable', (MyTable,), {})

database.init('test.db')

mytable.select()
```

Leads to:

```
>>> mytable.select()
<class 'peewee.MyDynamicTable'> SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."FieldA", "t1"."FieldB" FROM "mydynamictable" AS t1 []
```

But the name is correct:

```
>>> mytable
<class 'peewee.MyDynamicTable'>
>>> mytable._meta.db_table
'mydynamictable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peewee has aliased your table name. If you read the full query:

```
SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."FieldA", "t1"."FieldB"
FROM "mydynamictable" AS t1
```

The **"mydynamictable" AS t1** part aliases the table name to "t1", to make the query more compact. This is especially important when you have joins and need to disambiguate columns with the same name.